# Spivak's calculus - Prove (-a)^(-1) = -(a^(-1))

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I am trying to use the properties given in the first chapter of Spivak's calculus to prove that (-a)^(-1) = -(a^(-1)).

My proof:
We have on the right hand side, -(a^(-1)), which is equal to
-(1 * a^(-1))
= (-1) * a^(-1) [Using -(xy) = (-x)y]
= (-1) * a^(-1) * (-a) * ((-a)^(-1)) [Using multiplicative inverses]
= (-1) * (-a) * a^(-1) * ((-a)^(-1))
= a * a^(-1) * ((-a)^(-1)) [Using (-x)(-y) = xy]
= (-a)^(-1)

So we are able to prove it using 3 properties from the first chapter, but I feel like there is a simple way to prove it.

I also tried an alternate way by starting from the left hand side:
= (-a)^(-1)
= (-1*a)^(-1)
= ((-1)*a)^(-1)
= (-1)^(-1) * a^(-1) [Using (ab)^(-1) = a^(-1).b^(-1)]

However I have no idea how to prove that (-1)^(-1) = -1 using the properties given in the chapter so I am stuck here.

I would appreciate some help here with the second proof and also want to know if there is an overall easier way to prove this.

Comment: The definition of the mulitplicative inverse is that $x\cdot x^{-1} = 1$. So that $(-a)\cdot(-a^{-1}) = a\cdot a^{-1} = 1$ and this implies that $-a^{-1} = (-a)^{-1}$.

Comment: The crucial fact is that $-1\cdot -1 = -(-1)=1$. Spivak has proved this. Look on p. 7.

Comment: @PauloEstêvão shouldn't it be (-a).(-a)^(-1) = 1 though instead of (-a)(-(a^(-1))) = 1 based on the definition you provided? In that case, we run into the same problem for getting that minus sign out of the inverse

Comment: Sorry, I haven't expressed good enough. The multiplicative inverse of $x$ is the number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha x = x\alpha = 1$ and it's denoted as $x^{-1}$. Since $(-a)(-(a^{-1})) = (-1)(-1)(a)(a^{-1}) = 1$, then we have that $-(a^{-1})$ is the multiplicative inverse of $-a$, i.e. $-(a^{-1}) = (-a)^{-1}$.

Comment: @PauloEstêvão Thank you for the answer but your proof is the same as my first proof. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to express this, maybe in the form of (-1)^(-1) = -(1^(-1)) but by using the properties of multiplicative inverses and multiplicative identity only.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) is a MathJax guide. If you change `^(-1)` to `^{-1}` then surround each math environment with dollar signs, your calculations will be much more readable.

Comment: As I already said, use $(-1)^{-1} = -1 = -(1^{-1})$ and then the product property, which you seem to be fine using. This is not an actual exercise in Spivak, so I'm not sure what you're using and what you're not.

Comment: @nathananderson well, because $(-1)(-1) = 1$, it is it's own multiplicative inverse, so $(-1)^{-1} = - 1$.

Comment: Gee, I wonder who said this ages ago.

Comment: @TedShifrin Zamn mang calm down